# What is the storage capacity of a Mnesia database?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Some places state 2GB period. Some places state it depends up the number of nodes.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Quite large if your question is "what's the storage capacity of an mnesia database made up of a huge number of `disc_only_copies` tables" - you're largely limited by available disk space.

An easier question to answer is what's the maximum capacity of a single mnesia table of different types. `ram_copies` tables are limited by available memory. `disc_copies` tables are limited by their `dets` backend ([Hakan Mattsson on Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/~hakan/mnesia_consumption.txt)) - this limit is 4Gb of data at the moment.

So the simple answer is that simple `disc_copies` table can store up to 4Gb of data before they run into problems. (*Mnesia doesn't actually crash if you exceed the on-disk size limit - the ram_copies portion of the table continues running, so you can repair this by deleting data or making other arrangements at runtime*)

However if you consider other mnesia features, then the answer is more complicated.

- [`local_content`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#5.4) tables. If the
  table is a `local_content` table,
  then it can have different contents
  on each node in the mnesia cluster,
  so the capacity of the table is
  `4Gb * <number of nodes>`
- [fragmented tables](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#5.3). Mnesia supports user configurable table partitioning or sharding using table fragments. In this case you can effectively distribute and redistribute the data in your table over a number of primitive tables. These primitive tables can each have their own configuration - say one ram_copies table and the rest disc_only_copies tables. These primitive tables have the same size limits as mentioned earlier and now the effective capacity of the fragmented table is `4Gb * <number of fragments>`. (*Sadly if you fragment your table, you then have to modify your table access code to use `mnesia:activity/4` instead of `mnesia:write` and friends, but if you plan this in advance it's managable*)
- [external copies](http://code.google.com/p/mnesiaex/) If you like living on the extreme bleeding edge, you could apply the [mnesiaex](http://code.google.com/p/mnesiaex/) patches to mnesia and store your table data in an external system such as [Amazon S3](http://code.google.com/p/erlaws/) or [Tokyo Cabinet](http://code.google.com/p/tcerl/). In this case the capacity of the table is limited by the backend storage.

Comment: As far as I know dets can only handle 2GB files not 4GB, which will be the limit for disc_copies. There is an experimental 64-bit dets which can handle much larger files but no one has used it in production yet.

Comment: Can confirm it's 2GB, currently running into issues on production because I was counting on 4GB - be careful.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR:** the storage capacity of a Mnesia database is limited only<sup>*</sup> by available RAM.

<sup>*</sup> Assuming you use table types `ram_copies` or `disc_copies`. Also, if you store a lot of data in a `disc_copies` table, it needs to be read from disk at startup, which might increase startup time beyond what's acceptable.

---

This answer contradicts the two existing answers when it comes to tables of type `disc_copies`.  Let me first get a few general points out of the way:

- A mnesia table of type `ram_copies` is only limited by available RAM (except if you're on a 32-bit machine).  Data is stored in an ETS table.
- A mnesia table of type `disc_only_copies` is stored in a Dets table. Dets tables are limited to 2 GB, because of limits in the file format.
- The obvious way to circumvent that limit is to create more tables, possibly through [table fragmentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html).
- The schema is also stored in a Dets table, so the information describing all existing tables is also limited to 2 GB. You are likely to run into other limits before you hit that one, though.
- A mnesia table of type `disc_copies` is stored *both* in RAM and on disk, so it is limited by available RAM - and perhaps something else?

I'm going to try to show below that there is *no* specific limit imposed by Mnesia on the size of a `disc_copies` table.  Note however that many Erlang programmers believe that `disc_copies` tables are limited to 2 GB.  That is stated in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422259/113848) to this question, which at the time of writing outscores this answer by a factor of 7.

---

## disc_copies moved from dets to disk_log in 2001

It is commonly believed that `disc_copies` tables are backed by Dets tables.  As far as I can tell, this was the case until Erlang/OTP R7B-4 (released on 30th September 2001).  From [the README](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R7B-4.readme):

```
  -- mnesia -----------------------------------------------------------------

        OTP-3712 - Speed/load improvements disc_copies tables are not 
                   implemented with dets anymore.
```

Look at [the diff](https://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/commit/456bf42ac5efb77851334b271378737ea2df41b8#diff-bd5cbe94ceb22df01d6e87f8e3cbc187) for more details, in particular `mnesia_lib.erl` and `mnesia_loader.erl`.

---

## Sources supporting dets and a 2 / 4 GB limit

[archelaus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422259/113848) draws from http://erlang.org/~hakan/mnesia_consumption.txt, which explains that `disc_copies` tables reside in ets and dets tables.  However, looking at [the index for the directory](http://erlang.org/~hakan/), we see that this document is dated 1999:

```
[TXT] mnesia_consumption.txt  26-Oct-1999 10:57    10k
```

It makes sense that it would say this, as it was written two years before the change.

[Ray Boosen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421548/113848) draws from [the Erlang FAQ](http://erlang.org/faq/mnesia.html):

> ### 11.5  How much data can be stored in Mnesia?
>
> Dets uses 32 bit integers for file offsets, so the largest possible mnesia table (for now) is 4Gb.
>
> In practice your machine will slow to a crawl way before you reach this limit.

The FAQ has been saying that since at least January 2001 (see [the earliest copy in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20010121162200/http://www.erlang.org:80/faq/x1108.html)).  That means that this FAQ entry dates from before the switch to disk_log, and hasn't been updated for a long time.  (Anyway, the Dets table size limit is 2 GB, not 4 GB.)  I submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/matthiasl/Erlang-FAQ/pull/9) for the FAQ.

---

## Sources supporting higher limits

[The Learn You Some Erlang chapter on Mnesia](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/mnesia#from-record-to-table) says:

> **ram_copies**
>       This option makes it so all data is stored exclusively in ETS, so memory only. Memory should be limited to a theoretical 4GB (and practically around 3GB) for virtual machines compiled on 32 bits, but this limit is pushed further away on 64 bits virtual machines, assuming there is more than 4GB of memory available.
>
> **disc_only_copies**
>       This option means that the data is stored only in DETS. Disc only, and as such the storage is limited to DETS' 2GB limit.
>
> **disc_copies**
>       This option means that the data is stored both in ETS and on disk, so both memory and the hard disk. disc_copies tables are not limited by DETS limits, as Mnesia uses a complex system of transaction logs and checkpoints that allow to create a disk-based backup of the table in memory.

I'm not sure when this was written, but the text above exists in the [earliest Wayback Machine copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20120430101844/http://learnyousomeerlang.com/mnesia), dated April 2012.

In [a post on erlang-questions titled "beating mnesia to death (was RE: Using 4Gb of ram with Erlang VM)"](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2005-November/017730.html), dated 7th November 2005, Ulf Wiger writes:

> On a 16 GB machine, you can:
>
> - run 6 million simultaneous processes
>     (through use of erlang:hibernate, I was actually 
>     able to run 20 million - spawn time: 6.3 us, 
>     message passing time: 5.3 us, and I had 
>     1.8 GB to spare.)
> - populate mnesia with at least 12 GB of data, but
>     think through how you want to represent it, since
>     the 64-bit word size blows things up a bit.
> - keep a 10 GB+ disc_copy table in mnesia. The 
>     load times and log dump cost seem acceptable
>     (10 minutes to load, dumping takes a while but
>     runs in the background quite nicely.)

## Conclusions

The confusion seems to stem from missing or out-dated information from official sources:

- The Mnesia documentation doesn't mention any table size limits
- The Erlang FAQ says that Mnesia is subject to a 4 GB Dets size limit, but this answer was written before the dets to disk_log change
- The only other document on the erlang.org domain is Håkan Mattsson's document, dating from before the dets to disk_log change

LYSE seems to be the first "authoritative" source that mentions `disc_copies` tables not being subject to the Dets table size limit.

Answer (score 6):

As per the documentation, this is 4GB.  Section 11.5

http://erlang.org/faq/mnesia.html

Comment: Is this in anyway influenced by the number of nodes? Will Mnesia distribute/shard itself?

Comment: It's still the case as of Jun 2017