# Where are tables in Mnesia located?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I try to compare Mnesia with more traditional databases.

As I understand it tables in Mnesia can be located to (see [Memory consumption in Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/~hakan/mnesia_consumption.txt)):

- `ram_copies` - tables are stored in `ets`, so no durability as in ACID.
- `disc_copies` - tables are located to `ets` and `dets`, so the table can not be bigger than the available memory? And if the table are fragmented, the database can not be bigger than the available memory?
- `disc_only_copies` - tables are located `dets`, so no caching in memory and worse performance. And the size of the table are limited to the size of `dets` or the table has to be fragmented.

So if I want the performance of doing reads from RAM and the durability of writes to disc, then the size of the tables are very limited compared to a traditional RDBMS like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

I know that Mnesia aren't meant to replace traditional RDBMS:s, but can it be used as a big RDBMS or do I have to look for another database?

The server I will use is a VPS with limited amount of memory, around **512MB**, but I want good database performance.

Are `disc_copies` and the other types of tables in Mnesia so limited as I have understood? Can´t the database be partially on memory and a full copy on disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage capacity of the Mnesia database for the different types of tables has been discussed in this previous SO question:

[What is the storage capacity of a Mnesia database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421501/what-is-the-storage-capacity-of-a-mnesia-database)

where a great answer is already available.

Obviously (but I guess you've already seen it) the official doc is available at:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html

Also, reading from the [Mnesia FAQ](http://erlang.org/faq/mnesia.html):

> 11.5 How much data can be stored in Mnesia?
>
> Dets uses 32 bit integers for file
>   offsets, so the largest possible
>   mnesia table (for now) is 4Gb.
>
> In practice your machine will slow to
>   a crawl way before you reach this
>   limit.

Finally, Mnesia tables can be *fragmented*. This is discussed [here](http://www1.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#id2273885) and [there](http://www.trapexit.org/Mnesia_Table_Fragmentation).

These are my 2p.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand it, the tables will be limited to less than 512MB in my case unless I have `disc_only` which give bad performance. So better to look for another database then. Since I only have 512MB RAM.

Comment: Essentially what you want is caching and no, as far as I know, Mnesia doesn't do that for you. It's obviously possible to implement it, but it's not there waiting for you :)