# How much data a column of mnesia table can store

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

How much data can a column of mnesia can store.Is there any limit on it or we can store as much as we want.Any pointer?(If table is disc_only_copy)

Answer (score 3):

As with any potentially large data set (in terms of total entries, not total volume of bytes) the real question isn't how much you can cram into a single table, but how you want to partition the data and how unified or distinct those partitions should appear to the system.

In the context of a chat system, for example, you may want to be able to save the chat history forever, which is a reasonable goal. But you may not want all chat entries to be in the same table forever and ever (10 years? how long? who knows!) right next to chat entries made yesterday. You may also discover as time moves on that storing every chat message in a single table to be a painfully naive decision to overcome later on down the road.

So this brings up the issue of partitioning. How do you want to do it? (Staying within the context of a chat system, but easily transferrable to another problem...) By time? By channel? By user? By time and channel?

How do you want to locate the data later? This brings up obvious answers that are the same as above: By time? By channel? By user? By time and channel?

This issue exists whether you're dealing with Mnesia or with Postgres -- or any database -- when you're contemplating the storage of *lots* of entries. So think about your problem in the context of how you want to partition the data.

The second issue is the volume of the data in bytes, and the most natural representation of that data. Considering basic chat data, its not that hard to imagine simply plugging everything into the database. But if its a chat system that can have large files attached within a message, I would probably want to have those files stored as what they are (files) somewhere in a system made for that (like a file system!) and store only a reference to it in the database. If I were creating a movie archive I would certainly feel comfortable using Mnesia to store titles, actors, years, and a pointer (URL or file system path) to the movie, but I wouldn't dream of storing movie file data in my database, even if I was using Postgres (which can actually stand up to that sort of abuse... but think about new awkwardness of database dumps, backups and massive bottleneck introduced in the form of everyone's download/upload speed being whatever the core service's bandwidth to the database backend is!).

In addition to these issues, you want to think about how the data backend will interface with the rest of the system. What is the API you wish you could use? Write it now and think it through to see if its silly. Once it seems perfect, go back through critically and toss out any elements you don't have an *immediate* need to actually use *right now*.

So, that gives us:

- Partition scheme
- Context of future queries
- Volume of data in bytes
- Natural state of the different elements of data you want to store
- Interface to the overall system you wish you could use

When you start wondering how much data you can put into a database these are the questions you have to start asking yourself.

Now that all that's been written, here is a question that discusses Mnesia in terms of entries, bytes, and how many bytes different types of entries might represent: [What is the storage capacity of a Mnesia database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421501/what-is-the-storage-capacity-of-a-mnesia-database)

Answer (score 2):

Mnesia started as an in-memory database. It means that it is not designed to store large amount of data. When you ask yourself this question, it means you should look at another ejabberd backend.

Comment: This ignores the issue of scale. The meaning of "a lot" has drifted significantly in terms of byte-count, but a million entries is still rather a lot for a *single partition*, whether in Postgres or Mnesia.

Comment: I have been replying in the context of ejabberd and trust me when that question is asked, I know from experience that the user need to switch from Mnesia to another backend. This is indeed a very practical reply, but it should be good enough ;)